# Murraya koenigii (Curry leaf plant) root system

Tags: vegetables, containers, shrubs, container-gardening, roots

I am planning to grow Curry leaf plant in my balcony space using a pot.I would like to know what kind of root system this plant has. I mean to ask is it straight deep inside soil or more branched one? Based on root system I want to choose the pot shape and size(like narrow-necked pots/broad and short pots etc.)

I searched few resources like researchgate, wikipedia, Plant finder (Missouri botanical garden), Purdue website. But, these sources didn't mention about root system in this particular plant.

Comment: Hi Vikram. What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to [edit] your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: @theforestecologist In terms of botany/ecology I have very poor knowledge as I am not a researcher in that field.However, I searched several times but didn't find any reliable source explaining the root system. I am just interested in gardening with a little scientific touch.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Miracle fruit (Synsepalum dulcificum), the curry plant starts growing with a tall/deep tap root. If the pot is small, it starts circling at the bottom of the pot.

The pot size  really depends on how old/large the plant is. If the plant is less than 6-8” tall, star with 1 gallon plant. As it grows bigger, you may need to repot in the larger size pot almost every other year. The deeper the pot, the better. Do not star small plant in a large pot as it’s hard to control the water feeding and the plant is prone to getting root rot easily. The spider mites could be a huge problem for the indoor potted curry planted me experience.

I had my plants in pots first 3 to 7 years. I later transferred them in the ground here in the Bay Area, CA. At the age of about 13 years now, my curry tree is 12’ tall and healthy. All 3 trees are three different varieties of the Curry plant.

Comment: Hi choksi..thanks for your detailed explanation.Now I have already planted it in a big pot.After reading your answer I feel the pot is too large for my small plant.Now its already 3-4 months.Girth of the plant looks too less compared to size of the leaves and height.Winter is approaching (going to be 0 degree celsius in december).I am quite worried about the plant now.